# Java PBKDF2 With Hmac SHA512 high concurrent issue

Tags: java, pbkdf2

```
        SecretKeyFactory kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512);
        PBEKeySpec ks = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, count, keylen);
        SecretKey pbeKey = kf.generateSecret(ks);
        System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(pbeKey.getEncoded()));
```

Hello everyone, 
      I just use above code to generate encrypted key. But I found an urgent issue.  When I do a 30k high concurrent test, I find sometimes I will get some "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=" key. I think this should not be happened.
Do you guys have any suggestion? thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the value of `count`?

Comment: anything is ok, such as 1024

Comment: The point is that there count is a repetition count and there larger the more computation and the longer it takes to complete. 1024 repetitions takes about 8 sec on my laptop so at 30K instances that is about 4 minutes of work. That may not be a reasonable test.

Comment: We encountered the same issue with a high concurrent test. Our solution was to synchronize the method, but we are looking forward to a better solution. Anybody found the root of the problem and/or the solution for this issue?

Comment: @Dude, I don't think synchronize this method will fix this issue.

Comment: @jackli, we tested it in a VM with very low ressources settings (slow CPU) and could reproduce the problem on almost every run. With synchronised the problem did never occur on the same VM. Why do you think it will not fix the issue?

Comment: @Dude,because I have synchronize this method and make a high level concurrent test such as just for loop (800000 times), and got same error